# Disable keyboard layout switching for a specific app

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Is it possible to lock the keyboard layout for a specific application? I'm used to Ctrl+Shift combination, but it's inconvenient in some programming IDEs where I often use Ctrl+Shift+arrows for selection. So I want to disable the keyboard layout change shortcut for these applications (or change it to something else) while keeping it enabled elsewhere.